# Change Spinner'value or PopupWindow'value in order to change textview

Tags: android, spinner

In XActivity, I can get values which return from `Spinner` and `PopupWindow`.
Through the operation of two values, so I can get the third value to change `TextView`.
But I want once change `Spinner` or `PopupWindow`, `TextView` would be changed at once,not just through a button to get two values to change `TextView`.
What should I do?

```
public class SelectInsuranceVariety1Activity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private Spinner sp_plan;
private int int_plan = 1;
private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
private TextView vary_birthday,premium;
private String str_birthday;
private String[] births;
private int age;
private BigDecimal result = null;
private String prodCode;
private Intent intent;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_insurance_variety1);
    getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    intent = getIntent();
    prodCode = intent.getStringExtra("prodCode");
    String id = intent.getStringExtra("id");
    initView();
    getSpinnerPlan1();


}

private void initView() {
    findViewById(R.id.rl_dialog).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.iv_delete).setOnClickListener(this);
    vary_birthday = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vary_birthday);
    premium = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.premium);
    premium.setOnClickListener(this);
    vary_birthday.setOnClickListener(this);
    sp_plan = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_plan);

}
private int getSpinnerPlan1() {
    final ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter
            .createFromResource(SelectInsuranceVariety1Activity.this, R.array.pingan_arrays1,
                    R.layout.sp_style_province2);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    sp_plan.setAdapter(adapter);
    sp_plan.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int position,
                long id) {
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                int_plan = 1;
                break;
            case 1:
                int_plan = 5;
                break;
            case 2:
                int_plan = 8;
                break;
            case 3:
                int_plan = 11;
                break;
            case 4:
                int_plan = 16;
                break;


            }
            premium.setText(result.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> av) {

        }
    });
    return int_plan;
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.iv_delete:
        finish();
        break;
    case R.id.vary_birthday:
        DateTimeTool dtt = new DateTimeTool(inflater);
        dtt.bindPopup(v, SelectInsuranceVariety1Activity.this, vary_birthday);
        str_birthday = vary_birthday.getText().toString().trim();
        if (!str_birthday.equals("xxx")) {
            births = str_birthday.split("-");
            age = GetProductsPremium.GetAge(Integer.parseInt(births[0]), Integer.parseInt(births[1]), Integer.parseInt(births[2]));
            result = GetProductsPremium.GetProductPremium(prodCode, int_plan, age);
            LogUtil.e("SelectInsuranceVariety1Activity", "xx："+prodCode+"xx："+int_plan+"xx："+age);
            premium.setText(result.toString());
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: please share your code

Comment: I had changed my question,pls.read again